# two sets were not equal, but are equal after casting to list and cast back to set

Tags: python

Does anyone got this weird outcome before?

```py
>>> a == b
False
>>> list(sorted(a)) == list(sorted(b))
True
>>> set(list(a)) == set(list(b))
True
```

Where `a` and `b` above are `set` containing custom class instances.

This custom class inherited from `MutableMapping` with both `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` implemented as follows:

```py
def to_json(self) -> dict:
    # Code returning the data of this class

def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Model):
        return self.to_json() == other.to_json() and type(self) == type(other)
    elif isinstance(other, MutableMapping):
        return self.to_json() == other
    else:
        return False

def __hash__(self):
    d = self.to_json()

    hash_list = []

    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            v = tuple(v)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            v = tuple(v.items())
        elif isinstance(v, Model):
            v = hash(v)

        hash_list.append((k, v))

    return hash(tuple(hash_list))
```

I also test the hash code of these elements, it turns out it is the same. Below is my script to test:

```py
>>> [hash(m) for m in a]
[-1696378346402890742, 3465342798672228497, 5576155172607749152]
>>> [hash(m) for m in b]
[-1696378346402890742, 3465342798672228497, 5576155172607749152]
```

I've found that there's some work to do with `in`, but I don't know what should I implement. I also don't know why this is its behavior.

```py
>>> [(m in b) for m in a]
[False, False, False]
>>> [(m in b) for m in set(list(a))]
[False, False, False]
>>> [(m in set(list(b))) for m in a]
[True, True, True]
>>> [(m in set(list(b))) for m in set(list(b))]
[True, True, True]
```

Any fix that could potentially avoid/correct this weird behavior and the reason why this is how it works would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You're close, but you should be able to encapsulate this in a few lines, not 20 inoperative lines and no main program.

Comment: Actually I tried to minimize them, but because this implementation is a high-level code, I don't think I would be able to post a workable code without occupying the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the case of a list, the outcome is based on the result of `__eq__` only, whereas in the case of sets, it depends on `__hash__` as well.
In a minimal example like the following, you can see that lists of different objects with the same `__eq__`-value are evaluated to be the same, whereas sets are not. If you define a `__hash__`-function that depends on the value only (not on the instance), also the corresponding sets evaluate to equal.

```
class EA2:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(self) == type(other):
            return self.id == other.id
        else:
            return False

    def __hash__(self):
        #a = hash((id(self), self.id))
        a = self.id
        #a = randint(1,1000)
        print("hash= ", a)
        return a

print({EA2(1), EA2(2)} == {EA2(1), EA2(2)})
print(list({EA2(1), EA2(2)}) == list({EA2(1), EA2(2)}))
print(EA2(1) == EA2(1))
```

If your comparisons evaluate to False despite equal hashes, maybe there is a different implementation of the `__hash__`-function around (due to subclassing)?

Comment: I was also thinking about that my `__hash__()` maybe overridden and creating the falsy result, but as I listed in the question, both `[hash(m) for m in a]` and `[hash(m) for m in b]` yielded identical results

Comment: My thought was that maybe internally in the comparisons a different implementation might be used, so maybe try to track the calls to  ```__hash__``` somehow during debugging..